# App Engine (Google) Agent - safe to block? From an SEO perspective

Tags: google

I am seeing my website 'cloned' in a proxy site, which is on a subdomain of Google's appspot.com. And these 'clones' are being indexed, so I want to stop them.

I can do it, for appspot particulalury, by adding this to my`htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^AppEngine [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
```

Before I put it live, I just wanted to find out if this agent is actually used by Google for it's usual work/indexing/crawling. Would I be damaging my site's SEO if I block the AppEngine agent?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The AppEngine user agent is crawling done by apps created through Google's app engine.   These are third party applications that are not related to Googlebot or the Google search engine.

From an SEO standpoint it is safe to block AppEngine user agent requests.  Here is a thread on WebmasterWorld from folks who have done so:  https://www.webmasterworld.com/search_engine_spiders/4475764.htm

AppEngine apps have caused problems for others as well. Somebody complains about one [on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/143262/massive-crawling-requests-from-google-apps-engine-useragent).  If you find one that is crawling excessively, you can report it to Google here: http://code.google.com/support/bin/request.py?contact_type=AppEngineContact  The AppEngine user agent has the name of the app that is causing problems near the end: `appid: myexampleapp`.   You can use that when reporting to Google or learn more about that specific app by visiting its page: `http://myexampleapp.appspot.com`